# Document the Magic Link on the Relevant Help Page

Tags: feature-request, help-center, magic-links

Magic links are great, but I always forget what needs `help/` preceding the help topic (e.g. `[help/dont-ask]`) and which stand on their own (e.g. `[mcve]`, not to mention trying to remember  which things even *have* magic links.

After searching *yet again*, I usually end up at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/138482) on meta, where they are listed.

There is the *"Supported shorthand links"* section on the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) page, and the [Comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) section of the *Markdown help* page, but those haven't come up (for me) when searching (google or search the help center) — the answer I linked above *does* come up.

Also, if I'm already looking at the page I want to link to I have to search to figure out how I link to *that* page.

I suggest two things:

1. "Promote" help center "Comment formatting" page so it's easier to find
2. Document the magic link on the help page it links to, for example "Link to this page using the `[ask]` magic link"

Comment: I think they're just the URL slug...? I don't know, I never use them. I always type the links out manually, like a savage.

Comment: @CodyGray "ask" is `[ask]` but its url is ".../how-to-ask" if that's what you mean.